# Does google native client support sys/socket.h

Tags: google-nativeclient

I am aware that google native client uses pp::TCPSocket. does they also supports sys/socket.h.
I dont want to change the complete implemantation for socket. Hence want to clarify the things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `sys/socket.h` via the nacl_io library. See https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/coding/nacl_io.

Take a look at the `examples/demo/nacl_io` example in the sdk, it has a basic example of using `connect`/`send`/`recv`.

Note that TCP/UDP sockets are only available to Chrome Apps installed from the Chrome Web Store.

See https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network for information about using sockets within a Chrome App. This document explains how to use the JavaScript socket API. In Native Client, you'll use the BSD socket API, but you still need to specify the correct permissions in your App's manifest file.